# Receive 404 after uncomment enablePrettyUrl YII2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-url-manager

After uncomment enablePrettyUrl get 404 error

For example:

The requested URL /site/index was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at yiibasic.com Port 80

When I comment it again, everything is working

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
        ],
    ],
]
```

Can't understand what the problem is.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: Please add Apache configuration and logs.

Comment: question was edited

Answer (score 0):

The (Yii2) URL manager supports two URL formats:

the default URL format;
the pretty URL format.

By default 'enablePrettyUrl'   is set to false this mean  that the url have the format

```
your/index.php?r=post%2Fview&id=100
```

If you uncomment 'enablePrettyUrl' => true,

```
 'components' => [
  'urlManager' => [
    //'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
    ],
  ],
]
```

you enable the format for prettyUrl like:

```
/index.php/post/100
```

like as you easy see the two format are different so an explict call based on a format return a 404 error .. when you change the urlManager format enabling or disabling pretty url ..

you can call the url avoiding this problem  using  urlHelper

```
 use yii\helpers\Url;
 echo Url::to(['post/view', 'id' => 100]);
```

with this helper Yii2 create the proper url according on the pretty url enabling state in use

You can find a brief guide on yii2 routing here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html

Comment: Where I should use this helper? 
In config or in each file, clarify please

Comment: The Url::to(9 must be used  in each call for avoid the error if you change the prettyUrl status .. i have added  a link in answer  for a brief guide to yii2 routing

Answer (score 0):

After adding .htaccess file in your ./web folder (if using basic template ), you must then add some rules in the urlManager section of your web.php config file...see below

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'rules' => array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ],
```